# Merging two JSON files while summing up values

Tags: mule-studio, dataweave, mulesoft

I get two different files with stock information which I would like to join into one file while summing the data up, based on "pid".

payloadA

```
{
  "order": [
    {
      "pid": "a",
      "instock": "2"
    },
    {
      "pid": "b",
      "instock": "2"
    },
    {
      "pid": "c",
      "instock": "2"
    }
  ]
}
```

payloadB

```
{
  "order": [
    {
      "pid": "c",
      "instock": "2"
    },
    {
      "pid": "d",
      "instock": "2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Result
payloadA

```
{
  "order": [
    {
      "pid": "a",
      "instock": "2"
    },
    {
      "pid": "b",
      "instock": "2"
    },
    {
      "pid": "c",
      "instock": "4"
    },
    {
      "pid": "c",
      "instock": "2"
    }
  ]
}
```

But what I'm struggeling with are the edge cases:

- pids might be in both or as well in only one of the datasets
- payloadB might be empty

```
{
  "order": []
}
```

Comment: Looks like your output in incorrect. The last 'c' is probably a 'd'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following DataWeave expression:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::core::Arrays
var payloadA = {
  "order": [
    {
      "pid": "a",
      "instock": "2"
    },
    {
      "pid": "b",
      "instock": "2"
    },
    {
      "pid": "c",
      "instock": "2"
    }
  ]
}

var payloadB = {
  "order": [
    {
      "pid": "c",
      "instock": "2"
    },
    {
      "pid": "d",
      "instock": "2"
    }
  ]
}

---
"order": outerJoin(payloadA.order, payloadB.order, (itemA) -> itemA.pid, (itemB) -> itemB.pid) map (item, index) -> {
    "pid": item.l.pid default item.r.pid,
    "instock": (item.l.instock default 0) + (item.r.instock default 0)
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "order": [
    {
      "pid": "a",
      "instock": 2
    },
    {
      "pid": "b",
      "instock": 2
    },
    {
      "pid": "c",
      "instock": 4
    },
    {
      "pid": "d",
      "instock": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: An answer as quick as it is correct - thanks a lot! I was totally unaware of the "outerJoin"-function being applicable on arrays, not only databases, cool.

Comment: Glad it helped! You can check all the available DataWeave functions in the official documentation: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave